# MLP Construction with a Tesnor as input

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, computer-vision, torch

I am creating a simple neural network with one hidden layer for classification.
 My input data Set is ready and saved in .t7 file.

```
input =
{
  data : DoubleTensor - size: 1400x1002x3
  label : DoubleTensor - size: 1400
}
```

And this is the code of My MLP i have created

```
------------------------Neural Netwrok-------------------------

net = nn.Sequential()
inputs= "?" ; outputs=70; HUs= 25 --parameters & the problem is in my input "?" 
--that i am asking for.what shall i write there ? at the time i have the input 
--described above. 
        net:add( nn.Linear(inputs, HUs) ) 
        net:add(nn.ReLU()) -- Activation function
        net:add( nn.Linear(HUs, outputs) ) -- 70 output : classes of mpeg7

----------------------------------------------------------------------
print('NN : ' .. net:__tostring())
-------------------------Loss Function-------------------------
criterion=nn.ClassNLLCriterion() --Negative Log-Likelihood (NLL) Criterion
print('Duree NN : ' .. os.time())


---------------------- Loading Data ---------------------------------
trainset=torch.load('TrainSetTable.t7')

------------------------TRAINING MY NETWORK----------------------

trainer=nn.StochasticGradient(net,criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.0005
trainer.maxIteration = 10

print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('training epoch : ' .. trainer.maxIteration .. ', learning rate : ' .. trainer.learningRate .. ' , learning rate decay : ' .. trainer.learningRateDecay)
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')

trainer:train(trainset)
print('Duree Training : ' .. os.time())

net=net:double()
net:clearState()
torch.save('TrainedNN/NN_Mpeg7_10Epoch.t7',net)
print('Duree sauvegarde : ' .. os.time())
```

How can i say that the input to my NN is a Tensor ?

input.data (All) is a tensor of size: 1400x1002x3 contains my shapes: am working on mpeg7 dataset which contains 1400 shape and each shape for me is 1002*3 matrix.
input.label is a tesnor of size 1400 containing the corresponding label for each shape.

I am new with torch and lua.. but in the examples that i have seen like my code above, the data is imported and fed to the NN after constructing it. SO what shall i write as input for the NN before loading data ? how to make it "understand" that am going to feed it later data like this :

```
trainset=torch.load('TrainSetTable.t7')
trainset.data=trainset.data:view(980,1,1002,3)
```

{One_train_contour =  DoubleTensor - 1x1002x3 }

from a total of

```
{
 data(train_contours) : DoubleTensor - 980x1002x3
 label : DoubleTensor - size: 1400
}
```

and i have

```
{
 data(test_contours) : DoubleTensor - 420x1002x3
 label : DoubleTensor - size: 1400
}
```

what am i recommended to write in the line 
inputs= "?"

Answer (score 1):

Its implortant you define your Neural Networks input layers before you feed any data.
Please be mindful that the input to the NN is independant of the number of samples (in a classification network) and is solely dependant on the configuration of each sample of the data.

I am not familiar with mpeg, but if each sample of mpeg has a dimensions of 32x32
then your input should be 1024 (as is the case with MNIST dataset)

Source: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/